# How to access Local variables of functions when the function call has finished in python?

Tags: python, function, global-variables, local-variables

I found on the net that local variables of functions can't be accessed from outside when the function call has finished.I try to execute the program but it throws an error that variable is not defined. My code is

```
xyz=list()
n=0
def length(g):
    i=0
    n=g
    v=input("no of")
    while i<v:
        c=input("Enter the 1st dimension:")
        j=input("Enter the 2nd dimension:")
        i=i+1
        xyz.append(c)
        xyz.append(j)
        return c
        return j
        return n
def prod():
    global c
    for i in xyz:
        if n<c and n<j:
            print "Upload another"
        elif n==c and n==j:
            print "Accepted"
        else:
            print "Crop it"
       length(input("ENter the length"))
       prod()
       print xyz
```

It throws error like this

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Python27\pic.py", line 32, in 
>           prod()
>       `File "C:\Python27\pic.py", line 21, in prod
>       if n

Comment: Assuming that your indention gone bad while copy pasting it. why you have 3 return statements in `def length`. Its basic programming rule that a function cannot have more than 1 return statement.

Other thing is you should also declare `c` as global in `def length`. Then you will not get this error

Comment: @saurabhbaid - It's common for a function to have multiple `return` statements, although only one of them will execute.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I meant in the way he has written it, The control will return after first return so the later return statement would not execute. 
But I agree I havent choose my words correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you would want to do

```
xyz=list()
n=0
def length(g):
    i=0
    n=g
    v=input("no of")
    global xyz
    while i<v:
        c=input("Enter the 1st dimension:")
        j=input("Enter the 2nd dimension:")
        i=i+1
        xyz.append(c)
        xyz.append(j)
        return c,j,n


def prod():
    global xyz
    c,j,n = length(input("ENter the length"))
    for i in xyz:
        if n<c and n<j:
            print "Upload another"
        elif n==c and n==j:
            print "Accepted"
        else:
            print "Crop it"

prod()
print xyz
```

***Output***

```
ENter the length 2
no of 2
Enter the 1st dimension: 1
Enter the 2nd dimension: 2
Crop it
Crop it
[1, 2]
```